# Review & Send - legal notice is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, legal

I was in the process of submitting my CV for an opening and on the "Review & Send" tab noticed that the legal notice at the bottom is being cut off.

[image: legal notic is cut off]

Selecting the cut off text and pasting elsewhere revealed the following:

> By submitting your application you agree to our privacy policy and terms of service

Please fix - it is kinda important.

I am using the latest Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: So now we're expected to not only read the fine print, but also the hidden print? ;)

Comment: @Bart - Call it "extra" fine ;)

Comment: Are you using bigger fonts at the OS level or perhaps the browser is zoomed?

Comment: Oh right, I had [meant to report this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SJGMw.png) a few weeks ago...Whoops.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - Nope. All are at their defaults.

Comment: We've been reworking a lot of our CSS lately, I'm sure this is an artifact of that and will get cleaned up soon.  Thanks for the report, they are very useful as always

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be fixed on Chrome/Win7 now. Thanks for the report.

**EDIT**: Nope. Doesn't work with long cover letters.

**EDIT**: Yep. This is done now.

Comment: I will not call this fixed quite yet. If you have a long cover letter (enough to get a scroll bar on the submit page), the bottom still cuts off.

Comment: @Oded: AH! I see now. Let's see what we can do about that.

Comment: @Oded just committed a fix, can you let me know if this resolves it?

Comment: @mythz - Looks like it's sorted. Ta.